# Embed AngularJS directive in another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to implement some custom functions of Bootstrap Typeahed in a new directive.
Doing this, I need to embed the original Typeahed directive into mine, passing it, my parameters:

this is the original directive:

```
<div class="typeahead typeahead-lookup">
    <input ng-model="vm.myModel" 
           uib-typeahead="item as item.Formatted for item in vm.refreshSearch($viewValue)"
           typeahead-wait-ms="1000"
           typeahead-min-length="1"
           typeahead-editable="false"
           placeholder="SEARCH..."
           type="text"
           class="form-control">
</div>
```

this is my custom directive:

```
<select-lookup model="vm.myModel" 
               items="item as item.Formatted for item in vm.refreshSearch($viewValue)" 
</select-lookup>
```

and this is how I'm trying to implement it:

```
function selectLookup($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              model: "=",
              items: "@"
            },
            compile: function(element, attrs) {
                return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var template = '<div class="typeahead typeahead-lookup">' +
                                        '<input ng-model="model"' +
                                               'uib-typeahead="{{items}}"' +
                                               'typeahead-wait-ms="1000"' +
                                               'typeahead-min-length="1"' +
                                               'typeahead-editable="false"' +
                                               'placeholder="SEARCH..."' +
                                               'type="text"' +
                                               'class="form-control">' +
                                   '</div>';

                    element.html(template);

                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                };

            }
        };
    }
```

I'm getting problems passing parameters from my directive to the original Typeahead directive, especially the "items".
I got this error:  `Expected typeahead specification in form of "_modelValue_ (as _label_)? for _item_ in _collection_" but got "{{items}}"`.

Someone could help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `'uib-typeahead=' + attrs.items +` instead of `'uib-typeahead="{{items}}"'`

Typeahead is using a custom parser for that 'for in' syntax.  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L7

Comment: Thank you ChrisY... I've tried your solution but it seems to not work. I created a plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/IIcc3e7uE9FWDMzFPUqv?p=preview

Comment: The 'for in' syntax is evaluated with the scope of the directive and there are not states available. Updated the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3WowFCMa7zF8JQPlw498?p=preview

Comment: What if you have the directive separate. 
    `templateUrl:  '/lib/public/angular/views/customElements/typeahead.html',
       scope: {labelText: '@',data: '=', selectField: '@',displayField: '@', arrayList: '=', limit: '@', disabled: '=' }};`
And the template had 
    `<input
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="data"
        ng-disabled="disabled"
        type="text"
        name="{{data}}"
        placeholder="{{placeholderText}}"
        uib-typeahead="item.{{ selectField }} as item.{{ displayField }} for item in arrayList  | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:{{limit}}">`